# Compile for Android with Kony Enterprise Visualizer

Tags: android, temenos-quantum

I downloaded from git hub the sample project [Kony-Engagement-Service-Demo-Visualizer](https://github.com/kony/Kony-Engagement-Service-Demo-Visualizer). (

Im trying to build the Android App but I can't. Im getting this error:
 [exec-shell] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 [exec-shell]
 [exec-shell] - What went wrong:
 [exec-shell] A problem occurred configuring root project kmsapp1.
 [exec-shell] > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration :_debugApkCopy.
 [exec-shell] > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.0.
 [exec-shell] Required by:
 [exec-shell] :kmsapp1:unspecified
 [exec-shell]
 [exec-shell] - Try:
 [exec-shell] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
 [exec-shell]
 [exec-shell] BUILD FAILED
 [exec-shell]
 [exec-shell] Total time: 16.071 secs

I checked my Android SDK manager and the google services are installed (rev. 39).

I have installed Android Studio and is working (i.e. I can build and run sample Apps on my device).

A related issue may be this:

First I downloaded the Android SDK without Android studio and configured KonyVisualizer to point to that directory for SDKs. That brought me this error.

Then I downloaded the full Android Studio and pointed Kony Visualizer to point to c:\User\xxx\AppData\LocalªAndorid\Sdk. That reports (now) that no SDK is found there!

Answer (score 1):

So I found the solution and Im going to leave my own answer here. 
I got it from this Kony forum: https://community.kony.com/developer/forum/sdk-error-while-building-android-native-kony-visualizer-enterprise

Apparently, you have to replace the Android SDK tool 26 with version 25.

> The solution which worked for me, was getting the older SDK Tools
>   25.2.3 (found them not directly at Google pages but with a bit of searching online). After downloading them, replace the content of the
>   folder /tools with the old tools.

I hate the solution, since it means messing with Android Studio files, but its the only thing that worked for me, even after full re-install.